# Powershell crashing due to memory constants

Tags: powershell

I've got a server running around 500 powershell processes. Each of these processes are designed to make WMI calls across our environment. I've been careful to verify that I do not use up all of the server's available memory or CPU. When I have all 500 processes running, I'm at around 70% memory usage.

Just in case anybody is wondering how the individual processes are handled, they are executed using a gearman job worker. Basically a shell python script that calls a powershell script...times 500.

The issue i'm running into is that some of my powershell processes are crashing after running a few hours.

Some of the errors that I'm getting are:

```
A new guard page for the stack cannot be created
```

When I open event viewer, I see these events when processes crash

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: PowerShell
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: powershell.exe
P2: 6.3.9600.16394
P3: System.OutOfMemoryException
P4: System.OutOfMemoryException
P5: oft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.ReportExceptionFallback
P6: lization.EncodingTable.nativeCreateOpenFileMapping
P7: Consol.. main thread
P8: 
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\path

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: ID
Report Status: 2048
Hashed bucket:
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with powershell running out of memory, but the server is not peaked, and not all processes crash, it is sporadic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here are more crash results, the powershell fault module names are different from time to time:

```
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: powershell.exe
  Application Version:  6.3.9600.16384
  Application Timestamp:    52158733
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.16408
  Fault Module Timestamp:   523d45fa
  Exception Code:   c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 00069abb
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 624b
  Additional Information 2: 624b484d3cf74536f98239c741379147
  Additional Information 3: a901
  Additional Information 4: a901f876e92d1eb79eb3a513defef0c6

  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: powershell.exe
  Application Version:  6.3.9600.16384
  Application Timestamp:    52158733
  Fault Module Name:    combase.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.16408
  Fault Module Timestamp:   523d3001
  Exception Code:   c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 0001a360
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 81ca
  Additional Information 2: 81cae32566783b059420874b47802c3e
  Additional Information 3: b637
  Additional Information 4: b6375e6f6a866fc9d00393d4649231b8
```

Comment: I'm not sure the context you're working in (not familiar with the gearman worker) but you can easily issue WMI calls using native PowerShell utilizing jobs. Not knowing the script that might help you out.  Check out the -AsJob parameter on the Get-WmiObject cmdlet or the Start-Job cmdlet.

Comment: Is the job worker spinning up a 32-bit PowerShell or 64-bit?  The failing process is definitely running out of managed memory as indicated by the OutOfMemoryException.  :-)

Comment: @KeithHill I believe the processes are starting up as 32-bit powershell jobs. Is there a way I can confirm that, and is there a different path I need to call out to execute the 64-bit powershell processes?

Comment: @KeithHill I'm calling out powershell.exe from cmd prompt windows. I just verified that the version that I'm running is 64-bit powershell.

Comment: you may have some kind of memory leak in your script. try spawning 500 instances of a simple script that prints `hello world` or something, and see if it still crashes. better yet, share you script for review.

Comment: Are all the script processes the same (different parameters perhaps)? Spinning up a powershell.exe process for each script is probably not the best option. Look at Workflows or even using RunspacePools.

Comment: I was actually able to catch one of the process crashes, and It displayed "process is terminated due to stackoverflowexception" and the powershell process crashed.

This was actually displayed after I I saw this error: 
"test-connection insufficient memory available to continue the operation of the program."

I'm running a bunch of test-connection commands on many subnets at once before the actual script kicks off.

Comment: Here's the actual string:
      Test-Connection : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'       was thrown.

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at your max memory allocation per shell?

```
get-item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB
```

and if its too low changing this;

```
set-item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 2048
```

Comment: Thanks for this response, the max was set for 1024mb, I changed it to 2048mb and am re-trying my processes. We shall see!

Comment: Powershell is still crashing for some processes, see more details above

Comment: 1024MB * 500 processes = 500 gigs of memory. if you double it, we're talking about 1,000 gigs of memory. are you sure you aren't using all your system memory?

Comment: I would think that it would show my memory being peaked when I opened task manager...is that an incorrect thought? When I check the Memory usage, it is steady around 70% used (22GB).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't .Net have a [limit of memory?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/04/10/chat-question-memory-limits-for-32-bit-and-64-bit-processes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TaskManager to check on memory usage, you might try [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) instead. It sometimes gives very different results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the responses, it turns out that I had a memory leak in my powershell code that was causing memory usage to spike every now and then. Since I was not watching the server at every second, I missed when the memory usage spiked.

An interesting note, it appears that Powershell will not use more then 80% of available memory on a server before killing its own processes.

I had to increase the available memory to 56GB and now I'm not running into any issues whatsoever. I've been running 600 powershell processes for a week now and have not had one crash on me.